# Trouble with translating "brainwash the populace to believe"

Tags: grammar, translation, infinitives

I am not a native English speaker, so I am not sure I understand the bolded sentence correctly:

> The anti-hero is actually the main character in some contemporary works of literature. Guy Montag in "Fahrenheit 451," Winston Smith in "1984," who unwittingly ends up challenging those in power -- that is, **those who abuse their power to brainwash the populace to believe that the ills of society have been eliminated.**
>
> Source: An anti-hero of one's own - Tim Adams
> [TED-ed video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEjgDeSnBMs&feature=youtu.be&t=1m7s)

Is the infinitive "to believe" related to the populace or to those who abuse the power? I mean, I have two versions in my mind:

- They (who abuse the power) believe that the ills of society have been eliminated by brainwashing the populace.
- The populace believe that the ills of society have been eliminated because authorities have brainwashed them.

**Question**: Can you tell me which of the above versions is correct?

Comment: It's not a "sentence" - it's just a noun phrase identifying a certain group of people, who brainwash the population into believing a particular thing (that the ills of society have been eliminated). So it doesn't "say" anything in the sense you're thinking. If you put it in an *actual* sentence it might have a different meaning, such as *"This book encourages [power-abusers] to believe [blah blah]"*.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: "to brainwash the populace **into believing** that" is what is being meant here, right?

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you. I guess I understand what you mean. :)

Comment: @SrJoven Well, I am trying to translate it and need some guidance. It's not a question, but is it matter?

Comment: It matters because the purpose of this site is to provide answers to questions. Seeing as there is no question posed, no answer can be offered.

Comment: @Max: I think the syntax of your fragment is General Reference for ELU (so you should have posted on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) anyway). But it's impossible for us to analyse the syntax without having *the rest of the sentence*. If you got this from some source where it appears *as a complete sentence*, you're dealing with some kind of transcription error, since it's not syntactically valid as it stands.

Comment: I added the rest

Comment: @mplungjan: Following your edit giving the context, we can now confidently say *neither* of OP's interpretations is correct. What Adams is saying is that in the context of those two dystopias, the "people in power" who are being challenged are those [particular] people who brainwash the citizenry into thinking no more social ills remain to be tackled (presumably, because those in power have done such a good job of eliminating them).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ough, ok, next time I'll post there. The source is youtube video [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEjgDeSnBMs), see from 1:09.

Comment: @Max: It's a fairly complex NP (noun phrase), but I think the part you failed to understand is the two words immediately *before* the NP as originally quoted - ***that is***. What that means is the entire text ***those...eliminated*** is simply a more detailed expansion of the preceding use of ***those in power*** (the ones who are being "challenged").

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You're right, I didn't know that it is the noun phrase and considered it as sentence.

Comment: special thanks to @mplungjan. Now I know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split it up like this:

> those who [abuse their power [to brainwash the populace to believe [that the ills of society have been eliminated]]].

In other words

- this *whole* relative clause is talking about those who abuse their power
- what they are abusing their power to do is to brainwash the populace
- what they are brainwashing the populace to believe is that society's ills have been eliminated

---

Interestingly, there is a little ambiguity in the clause, but not in the place you described.

The ambiguity is whether they:

- have power, which they are abusing to brainwash the population, or
- have the power to brainwash the population, which they are abusing to make them believe that society's ills have been eliminated.

I think that most people would consider brainwashing itself to be an abuse of power, so the first interpretation would make more sense. (The other interpretation suggests that brainwashing itself is fine, but this particular use of the power to brainwash is what constitutes an abuse of that power.) However, grammatically it could be either.

Answer (score 0):

The infinitive "to believe" is related to the populace being brainwashed. The sentence is saying that those who abuse their power **want the populace to believe that the ills of society have been eliminated**.

If you were to relate it to those who abuse the power, you would have to omit "to", like this:

> Those who abuse their power to brainwash the populace <strike>to</strike> believe that the ills of society have been eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

In context:

> those in power -- that is, those who abuse their power to brainwash the populace to believe that the ills of society have been eliminated.

The use of *that is* means to further explain a preceding phrase. In this case, *those in power*.

In addition, it seems there's an implied [in order] that is missing, but would make sense in context:

A possible rephrasing:

> Those who [are already in power] abuse that power [in order] to brainwash the populace [so that they, the populace,] believe that the ills of society have been eliminated.